# What api should I use for Gui development, c++

Tags: c++, user-interface

I already know about Win32 api, and the toolkits Qt and Gtk+,however i have problems with all. Win32 is Os dependent, and the toolkits all involve using non pure c++ code that i find strange and complex. So what i want to know is can i creatre Os independent gui with just c++?"

Comment: Do you have a problem with wx?

Comment: @Joni not particularly if i have to i would rather use wxWidgets than the rest but i still want to know if i can create gui with just c++.

Comment: Well, no, you can't. Standard c++ does not define any graphics API or library.

Comment: *Any* gui library will look "strange and complex" when you've never done gui programming before.  The event-driven nature of gui programs is fundamentally different from what you might have been used to in writing console apps.  There are only two ways to make it stop looking "strange", read Petzold or jump in and get wet.  Petzold strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need a platform independent  GUI framework like Qt.

This Qt GUI code works on Windows, Linux and MacOS.

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLabel    label;

    label.setText("Hello World");

    label.show();

    a.exec();
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)

Answer (score 1):

there is a [Nana C++ library](http://www.nanapro.org/),with standard c++ and modern c++ style, it is easy to use. nanapro.sourceforge.net

Comment: What library would that be @jinhao?

Comment: Sorry,the URL was blocked. This library is under development, but it can work fine for small project. You can take a look at the blog at its sourceforge project page(sourceforge/p/nanapro/blog) for some information.